# javascript function currying, pass a function that passes the higher function parameters with currying

Tags: javascript, currying

I'm trying to provide a function `myFunction` to an object parameter named `update`, but I want the function values from `update` to be passed easily (or "curried") into `myFunction`.

I know I can do this

`const object = {update: (item1, item2) => myFunction(myValue1, myValue2, item1, item2)}`

But I would prefer to do something like `const object = {update: myFunction(myValue1, myValue2)}` and in `myFunction` do something like `const myFunction = (item1, item2) => (myValue1, myValue2) => { ... do something ... }`.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's fairly unclear how you would do this, given that you do not have `item1` and `item2` until the `object.update` is called.

Comment: @Taplar I am also not sure, only when `object.update` is called do I want to call `myFunction`. IT's for some `redux` type state changes

Comment: Why cannot you just use the first option.

Comment: @CodigoMorsa I can, it's just not as automated semantically as I would like, so doing it this way would save me some time

Comment: I think you just mixed up the order, `const myFunction = (myValue1, myValue2) => (item1, item2) => { ... do something ... }` would totally work.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not directly support currying like Haskell, for example,
but some functional library can be helpful

eg. https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry

Say if an original function defined as
`myFunction(myValue1, myValue2, item1, item2) { ... }`

then
`const curriedMyFn = R.Curry(myFunction)`
can be use as

`const object = {update: curriedMyFn(myValue1, myValue2)}`

Now object.update is myFunction specialized with myValue1 and myValue2.